# php xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml' error

Tags: php, xslt

Can one help me understand (and fix this error). The error reads:

`Warning: simplexml_load_file(): /home/jeffreycwitt/webapps/lombardpress_instances/petrusplaoul/lombardpress/phpfunctions/../../projectfiles/GitTextfiles/lectio1/lectio1.xml:2: parser warning : xmlParsePITarget: invalid name prefix 'xml' in home/jeffreycwitt/webapps/lombardpress_instances/petrusplaoul/lombardpress/phpfunctions/generalfunctions.php on line 47`

The error seems to have something to do with my schema delcarations at the beginning of my xml files.

The declaration at the beginning of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="https://bitbucket.org/lombardpress/lombardpress-schema/raw/master/LombardPressODD.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="https://bitbucket.org/lombardpress/lombardpress-schema/raw/master/LombardPressODD.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <teiHeader>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the warning.
On systems where I can turn of "display_errors" this hasn't been a problem. But now I'm working with a system in which I do not have access to the php.ini file.

Ideally, I'd like to solve the problem so that I don't have any warnings.
However, I need the schema declarations in place for other reasons.

Suggestions.
jw

Comment: try to short the path of archive

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: you mean the path of the file being processed? That would be annoying as it would take some doing.

Comment: eg: your archive is in the path way (folder)  /home/jeffreycwitt/webapps/lombardpress_instances/petrusplaoul/lombardpress/phpfunctions/../../projectfiles/GitTextfiles/lectio1/lectio1.xml maybe this way is to long

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure. Is there way to determine if simple_has a limit on the path length? And isn't the error complaining about the xml prefix within the document -- so it must be finding the document, right?

Comment: If you change `<?xml-model ` to `<?xml ` it should works.. but don't know why yet.

Comment: invalid name prefix 'xml' in [filename] the erro are in the file name  or path way

Comment: Sorry [filename] is confusing that was might fault. The error was just saying "in…" and then it is was suppling the name of the script trying to run the transformation.

Comment: @barell - perhaps, but xml validators will no longer recognize an attached schema if "<?xml-model" is changed to "<?xml"

Comment: Seems like PIs that are prefixed with `xml` must be listed explicitly as exceptions. See e.g. https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/parser.c?id=4c4653e587838a2cc78ddc03cb77749198f12c6b, line 194. In your case, "xml-stylesheet" should already be defined - perhaps you can locate it?

Comment: Mathias, I definitely think that's the problem. When I change from "xml-stylesheet" to "xml-model" the warning goes away. I'm using a shared hosting service so I put a ticket in to make this request. I will confirm that this solves the problem when they get back to me - meanwhile you should write this up as the answer -- it's a problem with a not-very-obvious solution. So hopefully, you answer might help someone else someday.

Answer (score 5):

There is one issue:

- The `<?xml` prefix is reserved for the first line

Use an underscore as a simple fix:

```
<?_xml-model href="https://bitbucket.org/lombardpress/lombardpress-schema/raw/master/LombardPressODD.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?_xml-model href="https://bitbucket.org/lombardpress/lombardpress-schema/raw/master/LombardPressODD.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
```

**References**

- [Namespaces in XML 1.0: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!